# Beginner question about getting reference to cin

Tags: c++

I'm having problems wrapping my head around this. I have a function

```
void foo(istream& input) {
     input = cin;
}
```

This fails (I'm assuming because cin isn't supposed to be "copyable".

however, this works

```
void foo(istream& input) {
    istream& baz = cin;
}
```

Is there a reason that I can get a reference to cin in baz but I cannot assign it to input?

Thanks

Comment: Is it because 

input = cin;

is similar to doing (if input was istream*) 
*input = cin;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
void foo(istream& input) {
     input = cin;
}
```

Doesn't create a reference. it invokes the `operator=` which is meant to copy things around.
This syntax however:

```
void foo(istream& input) {
    istream& baz = cin;
}
```

defines a new reference variable.

The key point is that in C++ you can't change a reference once you've declared it.
After the declaration the reference behaves as if it is the object referenced to itself. So using `operator=` on it tries to copy into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly reasonable.

Cloning something and creating alias to it are different operations.

Answer (score 0):

`& (reference)` actually works as a name alias, so all your changes are actually done on the object you're referring.

Hence, the first chunk of code fails, because you're working directly with your aliased stream which has a inaccessible (private) `operator=` in it.

Your second chunk of code actually means you're creating another name alias, therefore it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

A reference *must* be initialized, but *cannot* be assigned to. Unfortunately, initialization and assignment (can) both use `=`, so it's not always obvious which is which. In this case that difference is crucial though.

When you do `istream& baz = cin;`, you're initializing the reference, but doing nothing to the `istream` itself. When you do `input = cin;`, it's *not* initialization, because at that point `input` has already been initialized. That leaves only one other possibility: assignment. Since you can't assign to the reference itself, however, it's interpreted as attempting to assign `cin` to the stream referenced by `input`. Since streams can't be assigned, the compiler rejects that.